# Using python3.0 and above to enter a string into a text box and getting the results from a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-post

The HTML to the site is as follows

```
<html>
<head>
<title>FAS-ESS web server</title>
</head>

<body>
<body bgcolor="#00336677" link="#FFFF00" vlink="#00FFFF" alink="#00FF00" text="#FFFFFF">
<h1><center>FAS-ESS web server</center></h1>
<p><center>(provided by the <a href="http://genes.mit.edu/burgelab/">Burge Lab</a>)        </center></p>

<form action="http://genes.mit.edu/cgi-bin/fas-ess.pl" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="set" value="FAS-hex2" checked>FAS-hex2
(<a href="fas-hex2.txt">set</a>)<br />
<input type="radio" name="set" value="FAS-hex3">FAS-hex3
(<a href="fas-hex3.txt">set</a>)

<p>Sequence(s):<br />
<textarea name="sequence" rows="12" cols="72"></textarea><br />
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</p>
</form>

<p>Notes:</p>
<ul>
<li>You can enter a single sequence or multiple sequences in FASTA format.</li>
<li>Non-letters will be removed from sequences.</li>
<li>Lowercase letters will be converted to uppercase.</li>
<li>T and U are considered the same.</li>
</ul>

<p>Reference:<br />
Wang, Z., Rolish, M. E., Yeo, G., Tung, V., Mawson, M. and
Burge, C. B. (2004). Systematic identification and analysis of exonic
splicing silencers. <i>Cell</i> <b>119</b>, 831-845.</p>

<p>Please send feedback to Mike Rolish (merolish at mit dot edu).</p>

<p><a href="http://genes.mit.edu/burgelab/">Burge Lab home</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my python code:

```
import os
import sys
import urllib
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request


site = "http://genes.mit.edu/fas-ess/"
def getinfo(info):
    form_data = {'sequence':info}
    params = urllib.parse.urlencode(form_data)
    request = urllib.request.Request(site,bytes(params,encoding='UTF-8'))
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    print (response.read().decode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    info = '>NM_000015\nATGGACATTGAAGCATATTTTGAAAGAATTGGCTATAAGAACTCTAGGAACAAATTGGACTTGGAAACATTAACTGACATTCTTGAGCACCAGATCCGGGCTGTTCCCTTTGAGAACCTTAACATGCATTGTGGGCAAGCCATGGAGTTGGGCTTAGAGGCTATTTTTGATCACATTGTAAGAAGAAACCGGGGTGGGTGGTGTCTCCAGGTCAATCAACTTCTGTACTGGGCTCTGACCACAATCGGTTTTCAGACCACAATGTTAGGAGGGTATTTTTACATCCCTCCAGTTAACAAATACAGCACTGGCATGGTTCACCTTCTCCTGCAGGTGACCATTGACGGCAGGAATTACATTGTCGATGCTGGGTCTGGAAGCTCCTCCCAGATGTGGCAGCCTCTAGAATTAATTTCTGGGAAGGATCAGCCTCAGGTGCCTTGCATTTTCTGCTTGACAGAAGAGAGAGGAATCTGGTACCTGGACCAAATCAGGAGAGAGCAGTATATTACAAACAAAGAATTTCTTAATTCTCATCTCCTGCCAAAGAAGAAACACCAAAAAATATACTTATTTACGCTTGAACCTCGAACAATTGAAGATTTTGAGTCTATGAATACATACCTGCAGACGTCTCCAACATCTTCATTTATAACCACATCATTTTGTTCCTTGCAGACCCCAGAAGGGGTTTACTGTTTGGTGGGCTTCATCCTCACCTATAGAAAATTCAATTATAAAGACAATACAGATCTGGTCGAGTTTAAAACTCTCACTGAGGAAGAGGTTGAAGAAGTGCTGAGAAATATATTTAAGATTTCCTTGGGGAGAAATCTCGTGCCCAAACCTGGTGATGGATCCCTTACTATTTAG'
    getinfo(info)
```

### Full Explenation:

What I am trying to do is enter the given string into the website, submit it, and then grab the resulting page.  I have tried translating the other thread that try this using python before 3.0 with urllib2 but the only thing I am getting in return is the original websites html.

Thank you for taking a look.

I would invite you to try out the website:
http://genes.mit.edu/fas-ess/

with this query

">NM_000015
ATGGACATTGAAGCATATTTTGAAAGAATTGGCTATAAGAACTCTAGGAACAAATTGGACTTGGAAACATTAACTGACATTCTTGAGCACCAGATCCGGGCTGTTCCCTTTGAGAACCTTAACATGCATTGTGGGCAAGCCATGGAGTTGGGCTTAGAGGCTATTTTTGATCACATTGTAAGAAGAAACCGGGGTGGGTGGTGTCTCCAGGTCAATCAACTTCTGTACTGGGCTCTGACCACAATCGGTTTTCAGACCACAATGTTAGGAGGGTATTTTTACATCCCTCCAGTTAACAAATACAGCACTGGCATGGTTCACCTTCTCCTGCAGGTGACCATTGACGGCAGGAATTACATTGTCGATGCTGGGTCTGGAAGCTCCTCCCAGATGTGGCAGCCTCTAGAATTAATTTCTGGGAAGGATCAGCCTCAGGTGCCTTGCATTTTCTGCTTGACAGAAGAGAGAGGAATCTGGTACCTGGACCAAATCAGGAGAGAGCAGTATATTACAAACAAAGAATTTCTTAATTCTCATCTCCTGCCAAAGAAGAAACACCAAAAAATATACTTATTTACGCTTGAACCTCGAACAATTGAAGATTTTGAGTCTATGAATACATACCTGCAGACGTCTCCAACATCTTCATTTATAACCACATCATTTTGTTCCTTGCAGACCCCAGAAGGGGTTTACTGTTTGGTGGGCTTCATCCTCACCTATAGAAAATTCAATTATAAAGACAATACAGATCTGGTCGAGTTTAAAACTCTCACTGAGGAAGAGGTTGAAGAAGTGCTGAGAAATATATTTAAGATTTCCTTGGGGAGAAATCTCGTGCCCAAACCTGGTGATGGATCCCTTACTATTTAG"

Comment: You're supposed to send requests to the endpoint of the form... eg: `http://genes.mit.edu/cgi-bin/fas-ess.pl` Try changing the `site` variable to that and see what you get

Comment: I get an error "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error"

Comment: @JonClements you were right on the site that I had to send it to but I was missing a few parameters in my data when I submitted.  My form_data line became  "form_data = {'set':'FAS-hex3','sequence':info,'submit':'Submit'}" and it worked! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the send request like Jon Clements explained and add the `set` to your form_data:

```
site = "http://genes.mit.edu/cgi-bin/fas-ess.pl"
def getinfo(info):
    form_data = {'sequence':info, 'set':'FAS-hex2'}
```

Comment: @Eric Thomas.. see you already got it yourself! It took me some time to look at your problem so didn't read your comment to JonClements.

Comment: That is cool, I went ahead and marked this because it might be useful to future questions.  There really isn't a clear guide to this at the time.